# IE8 background images can't resize and offset

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, background-image

The background images are normal under IE9, but don't work in IE8.

The URL is http://beta.ydfzxy.com, and the default CSS file is http://code.google.com/p/ydfzxy/source/browse/trunk/beta/wp-content/themes/pavo/css/screen/default.css

Can anyone tell me what's wrong and correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`background-size` is not supported in IE8 and older. You need a javascript solution to make it work in IE8.

I use this method with a `<img>` positioned behind all content: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: This is quite fun to play around with the background i made a example with easing scroll and css scrolling bar. -
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dv0lcdwg71m8bt2/VrOPVOq6pz